# Partitions comprised only of divisors

Tags: nt.number-theory, partitions, co.combinatorics

How many of the partitions of a natural number $n$ are comprised only of its divisors? That is, if $$p(n)=\sum_{\sum_{1}^n kj_k=n:j_k\geq 0} 1_{\[j_1,j_2,...\]},$$
is the ordinary partition function (i.e. the total number of partitions of $n$), then I want to know something about the counting function $$s(n)=\sum_{\sum_{d|n}dj_d=n:j_d\geq 0}1_{[j_1,...,j_d,...]}.$$

I would be happy to hear of anything that is known about this function, but I am particularly interested in (a) its generating functions, and (b) a bijection between this restricted partition and another (hopefully more intuitive to count) restricted partition. Any insights would be welcome.

I should add that google finds a number of papers that study "partitions of $n$ into divisors of $m$", e.g. Gupta, 1970s, but those methods reduce to rather vacuous statements when evaluated at $m=n$.

Thanks!

Comment: It's tabulated at http://oeis.org/A018818 but I don't see any answers there. 

Comment: Yes, the only thing referred to there that possibly gives a clue is the integral found when you evaluate the generating function used by Gupta at $m=n$. By Cauchy's theorem and the fact that $\sum_{d|n}\phi(d)=n$, you get $$s(n)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}\prod_{d|n}q^{-\phi(d)}(1-q^d)^{-1}\frac{dq}{q}.$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bounds for this partition function were given by the editors of The American Mathematical Monthly, Paul Erdos, and Andrew Odlyzko in the March 1992 issue, p. 277, as a solution to Advance Problem number 6640. The bounds they prove are:

$$
({\tau(n)}/{2}-1)(\log n + O({\log n}/{\log \log n}))
\leq 
\log s(n)
\leq
({\tau (n)}/{2})\log n + O(\log \log n),
$$
where $\tau(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$.

Comment: Great - I'd wondered if this had cropped up. Thank you. Is an electronic copy available online do you know? I can only fond the contents page, in which the problem solutions are not listed.

Comment: A copy can be obtained from JSTOR: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2325075 It looks like you should be able to see the article for free by creating a "My JSTOR" account. 

Comment: Ah! Douglas, you didn't mention that it was you who set the problem! Not surprisingly their proof is marvellous, but it doesn't use anything deeper than the evaluation at $m=n$ of the coefficients of the polynomial mentioned above (though evidently this result is certainly not a trivial deployment of it). None-the-less, I remain particularly curious as yo what more is known... What were your interests in this function? How come you posed the problem? 

Comment: I considered the function arround 1982 during a time I was doing a lot of reading on partitions and analytic number theory. My motivation was that the ordinary partition function $P(n)$ has very nice asymptotics, while in multiplicative number theory, much more irregular behavior is typical. I created the function as an interesting synthesis. I thought that the generating function would likely provide purchase for finding asymptotics. In 1989 I presented the problem at a conference, where Erdos and Odlyzko got excited about it. Monthly editors then asked me to pose it as a problem.

Comment: And indeed it did provide purchase. Well, thank you for the insight, I'm very grateful. So, do you know if the upper bound is tight, or at least that $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{s(n)}{n^{\tau(n)/2}}=\infty$$? The $\liminf=1$ and this is the $\lim$ through both primes and squares of primes, but the upper bound (if tight) still suggests a lot of irregularity, specifically that $s(n)^{1/\tau(n)}=O(n^{1/2}+\epsilon)$ for every $\epsilon>0$ but not $\epsilon=0$, which is the "best-case scenario" in a lot of multiplicative number theory.

Comment: Obviously that should read $s(n)^{1/\tau(n)}=O(n^{1/2+\epsilon})$.

Comment: Please ignore the (irrelevant) mention of the other limits above - it is incorrect (except for the limit through primes). The only relevant point is the question of the upper bound and the limit superior. 

Comment: I don't know about the limit superior. You must have meant $\lim \inf =0$, since $s(p)=\tau(p) =2$, making the ratio $s(n)/n^{\tau(n)/2}=2/p$ for $n=p$, prime. As far as the upper bound is concerned, when one considers the sequence of powers of $2$, the complete asymptotics of $s(n)$ are known, so the error in the bound can be studied quite easily in that case.